# Struct forward list items disapearing?

Tags: c++, pointers, forward-list

This piece of code is getting quite on my nerves. Been debugging it for a while, cant believe how rusty i've got on c++.

I'm trying to model a graph to run some simple algorithms on, but that doesn't seem to work out so well. Every vertex contains a forward list to his neighbors, however when inserting the elements their obviously present.. Until I reach the print function; at that time the forward list is empty.

I've tried to allocate the forward_list using new aswell, as scoping could be an explication for it.. No luck there either..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <forward_list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Vertex Vertex;

struct Vertex {
    unsigned id;
    forward_list<Vertex*>_next;

    bool operator < (const Vertex &other) const { return id < other.id; };
};

typedef set<Vertex> Graph;
typedef vector<Vertex*> Index;
typedef pair<unsigned, unsigned> Edge;
typedef forward_list<Vertex*> Neighbors;


// Function:    process_line()
// Purpose:     process a specific line from the file.
// Params:      line to process
Edge process_line(string line){
    unsigned vertex_from;
    unsigned vertex_to;

    int idx = line.find(" ");

    vertex_from = (unsigned)stoul(line.substr(0, idx));
    vertex_to = (unsigned)stoul(line.substr(idx+1, line.length()));

    return make_pair(vertex_from, vertex_to);
}


// Function:    load_graph()
// Purpose:     load graph from file in relation
// Params:      path, and reference to graph and index
bool load_graph(string file_path, Graph &graph, Index &index){
    string line;
    ifstream file(file_path);
    bool foundEmptyLine = false;

    if(file.is_open()){
        while(getline(file, line)){
            if(line.empty()){
                foundEmptyLine = true;
                continue;
            }

            if(!foundEmptyLine){
                // processing vertexes
                Vertex *vertex = new Vertex;

                vertex->id = stoul(line);
                graph.insert(*vertex);
                index.emplace_back(vertex);
            }else{
                //Processing relations
                Edge edge = process_line(line);

                Vertex* neighbor = index.at(edge.second);
                Vertex* source = index.at(edge.first);

                // Lookup edge in index
                source->_next.emplace_front(neighbor);

                // ITEMS PRESENT! <----------------------
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Unable to open " << file_path;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void print_graph(Graph &graph){
    for(Graph::iterator it = graph.begin(); it != graph.end(); ++it){
        Neighbors neighs = it->_next;

        cout << "Node: " << it->id << " neighbors: " neighs.empty();

        cout << endl;
    }
}


// Entry point.
int main() {
    Graph graph;
    Index index;

    load_graph("graph_1.txt", graph, index);
    print_graph(graph);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is once again the same problem as yesterday.

Let's try to recapitulate the `std::set`

- Since C++11 the `iterator` of a `std::set` is always an iterator to `const value_type`. This is because when we change an entry of a `std::set` this entry would need to be placed somewhere else in the data structure.
- When we insert something into a `std::set`, two signatures are provided:

  ```
  pair<iterator,bool> insert (const value_type& val);
  pair<iterator,bool> insert (value_type&& val);
  ```

  But in any case the insertion *copies* or *moves* the element into the container.

So in your case when you do

```
Vertex *vertex = new Vertex;
vertex->id = stoul(line);
graph.insert(*vertex);
index.emplace_back(vertex);
```

First you allocate memory (which by the way you never delete! You will leak much memory, which you can check using valgrind). Then you insert a copy of your vertex into the `std::set` and insert the pointer of your allocated memory into the `std::vector`.

When you then later do

```
Vertex* neighbor = index.at(edge.second);
Vertex* source = index.at(edge.first);

// Lookup edge in index
source->_next.emplace_front(neighbor);
```

You take the Vertex from your vector (remember, this is the vertex which you allocated with `new`). And insert another vertex (also dynamically allocated) into its `std::forward_list`. **But**:  They have nothing to do with the vertex which are in your `std::set`.

So when you then later go through your `std::set`:

```
for (Graph::iterator it = graph.begin(); it != graph.end(); ++it)
```

This is completely unrelated to what you did when when inserting the edges - and all `std::forward_list`s are empty.

*Side notes*:

- This is something you had to use in C, but not in C++!

  ```
  typedef struct Vertex Vertex;
  ```
- This one you should place above:

  ```
  typedef forward_list<Vertex*> Neighbors;
  ```

  It doesn't make sense to declare the type of `Neighbors` after you declared `_next`, because `_next` has this type.
- Use `const` whereever you can, and `cbegin` / `cend` whereever you can (I already told you this yesterday), e.g.:

  ```
  for(Graph::iterator it = graph.cbegin(); it != graph.cend(); ++it){
  ```

  It doesn't make a difference here, but if you change the type of `graph` at some point, `begin()` may return a iterator to `value_type` instead of `const value_type`

Comment: Thank you for your effort once again. I've missed the fact that the set copies the elements, in antithesis to the vector. Hence why inserting references into the set made the whole thing work. Used the const_iterator tip in my working version as well.

Comment: I recommend using vector<Vertex> for your index, set<Vertex*, SomeCompareOp> for graph and forward_list<Vertex*> for Neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the graph to keep references to the existing vertices. I'm still not sure why this fixed it---but felt like giving a heads-up.